# Functions $f$ whose values are between $-1$ and $1$, and so do its derivatives.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, trigonometry, inequality

> Is $f(x)=\sin(x)$ or $f(x)=\cos(x)$ the only function on $\Bbb R$ such that $f^{(n)}(\Bbb R) \subset [-1,1]$ for all $n=0,1,\ldots$ and $f^{(k)}(0)=1$ for some $k\in \Bbb N$?

I found [this question for $k=1$ on Codidact](https://math.codidact.com/posts/286961). I originally though that it would be easy to find functions satisfying the criteria, but surprisingly all my attempts have failed.

Note that for $k=1$ it is easy to see that out of the parametric family $f(x)=a\sin(bx)$ only the function with $a=b=1$ satisfies the criteria. I though that there would be a way modify the sine to make it oscillate progressively slower as going away from $0$, but I would always get one of the higher-order derivatives out of the $[-1,1]$ range.

Comment: Two comments:
1) I believe you want to exclude the constant functios.
2) As you say $f(x)=asin(bx)$ can work, but in many more cases you say. The derivates are always of the form $\pm ab^n sen(bx)$ or $\pm ab^n cos(bx)$. In both cases, if $0 \leq a, b \leq 1$ then $0 \leq ab^n \leq 1$ for all $n$, as well as $cos(bx)$ and $sin(bx)$.

Comment: Also think about the function:
$f(x)=\frac{sen(x)}{x}$ if $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=1$.

Comment: Just to let you know: I'm the one who wrote that question on codidact.I think it was originally inspired by a question here, but I simply don't remember anymore.

Comment: For *periodic functions* see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/108630/42969. It is also mentioned in a comment (but without proof) that the statement holds without assuming periodicity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1863239/42969

Comment: @MartinR Thanks a lot for the reference, it answers it for $k=1$, I can't see now if the other values of $k$ then follow.

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity Thanks for sharing the question on Codidact, I hope that one day there will be a vibrant community there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows from

- [If $f$ is a smooth real valued function on real line such that $f'(0)=1$ and $|f^{(n)} (x)|$ is uniformly bounded by $1$ , then $f(x)=\sin x$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1863239/42969)

that $f^{(k-1)}(x) = \sin(x)$, that is the difficult part and answers your question for $k=1$.

The general case now follows by repeated integration: $f^{(k-1)}(x) = \sin(x)$ implies that
$$
f^{(k-2)}(x) = -\cos(x) + C
$$
for some constant $C$, and  $f^{(k-2)}(\Bbb R) \subset [-1,1]$ is only possible if $C=0$.

Continuing in that way we get $f^{(k-3)}(x) = -\sin(x)$ and so on,  and finally that $f$ is one of the functions $\sin, \cos, -\sin$, or $-\cos$.