# Function $f$ with values and derivatives between $-1$ and $1$, and $\sup_k f^{(k)}(0)=1$.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, trigonometry, inequality

> Are the functions $\pm \sin(x)$ and $\pm \cos(x)$ the only functions $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ with $f^{(n)}(\Bbb R)\subset [-1,1]$ for all $n=0,1,\ldots$ and $\sup_{k\in \Bbb N} f^{(k)}(0)=1$.

If the supremum is attained at a finite $k$, then the answer follows from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1863239/if-f-is-a-smooth-real-valued-function-on-real-line-such-that-f0-1-and-f) as was proved here: [Functions $f$ whose values are between $-1$ and $1$, and so do its derivatives.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4630409/1134951) Otherwise there muust be a strictly increasing sequence $\{k_n\}$ such that $f^{(k_n)}(0)\to 1$ as $n\to \infty$. Is this condition sufficient in order to make the conclusions as in the linked posts?